# Multilinear transformations being determined by their values on basis elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, tensors

The following is stated in the book *Analysis on Manifolds by James Munkres*

> Just as is the case with linear transformations, a multilinear transformation
>   is entirely determined once one knows its values on basis elements. That
>   we now prove.

And then he gives the following lemma.

> **Lemma 26.2** Let $a_1, \dots, a_n$ be a basis for $V$. If $f, g : V^k \to \mathbb{R}$ are $k$-tensors on $V$ and if $$f\left(a_{i_1}, \dots, a_{i_k}\right) = g\left(a_{i_1}, \dots, a_{i_k}\right) $$ for every $k$-tuple $I = (i_1, \dots, i_k)$ of integers from the set $\{1, \dots, n\}$ then $f=g$.

Now what I don't understand is why to we even need the following in the above lemma

> "for every $k$-tuple $I = (i_1, \dots, i_k)$ of integers from the set $\{1, \dots, n\}$"

Because $V^k$ has dimension $k \cdot n$ since $V$ has dimension $n$, and has as basis elements \begin{align*}&(a_1, 0,  \dots, 0), \dots, &(a_n,0, \dots, 0), \\
&(0, a_1, \dots, 0), \dots, &(0, a_n, \dots, 0), \\
 \ \ \ &. &. \\
 \ \ \ &. &. \\
 \ \ \ &. &. \\
&(0, 0, \dots, a_1), \dots, &(0, 0, \dots, a_n)
\end{align*}

So if $\mathcal{B}$ was the set of basis elements of $V^k$ above then I'd say that the following proposed lemma would make more sense

> **Proposed Lemma:** Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. If $f, g : V^k \to \mathbb{R}$ are $k$-tensors on $V$ and if $$f(\alpha) = g(\alpha)$$ for every $\alpha \in \mathcal{B}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $V^k$, then $f= g$

Furthermore the same part of Lemma 26.2

> "for every $k$-tuple $I = (i_1, \dots, i_k)$ of integers from the set $\{1, \dots, n\}$"

Taken literally gives $n^k$ possible $k$-tuples, which would correspond to checking to see if the values of $f$ and $g$ agree on $n^k$ basis elements, which confuses me since $\dim(V^k) = kn$

I'm sure that Lemma 26.2 must be correct and I'm just making some error somewhere, if so could someone please point out what that error is.

Comment: take a look at how this construction looks for $V=\Bbb R^1$ or  $V=\Bbb R^2$ or $V=\Bbb R^3$ with $k=1$ or $=2$ or $k=3$

Comment: @janmarqz Okay so take the case $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $k=2$, suppose $f, g : V^2 = \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ are two $2$-tensors, by the above theorem we need to show $$f(e_1, e_1) = g(e_1, e_1);\\ f(e_1, e_2) = g(e_1, e_2);\\ f(e_2, e_1) = g(e_2, e_1); \\  f(e_2, e_2) = g(e_2, e_2);$$ for basis elements $e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $e_2 = (0, 1)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But for example $(e_1, e_1) = (1, 0, 1, 0)$ is not a basis element of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: So I take it that Munkres is referring to basis elements of $V$ as opposed to $V^k$

Comment: for bilinear maps $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ (which is a vector space) you only need the 4 basic "vectors": 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)$$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right)$$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\1&0\end{array}\right)$$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: @janmarqz But that's not what the theorem above asserts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of $\underbrace{V\otimes\dots\otimes V}_{k \text{ times}} = \bigotimes^k V$ is $n^k$, even though the dimension of $V^k$ is $kn$. We're talking about *multilinear* maps on $V^k$, not linear maps. (Note that $n=k=2$ is a bad example to pick, since then $kn = n^k$. :))

**EDIT**: I should comment that the vector space of multilinear maps on $V^k$ is isomorphic to $\big({}\bigotimes^k V\big)^*$, but dimensions are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ted! Just one follow up question, you're saying then that Munkres is talking about basis elements from $\bigotimes^k V$ and not $V^k$, correct?

Comment: Right. That's why we're considering the $n^k$ $k$-tuples $(a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_k})$.

Comment: Okay thanks again Ted! :)